# Simple means to get user's roles from AD?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I am writing a standalone application that needs to, given a AD account name, figure out if the user is a member of a particular group. I am writing the application in .NET (C#). The structure in AD looks like this:

- Organization

  - Team 1

    - David *(user)*
- Groups

  - Application A

    - Team 1 *(group from above)*

Just listing the memberships for David will not show that he is a member of the Application A group.

I understand from Microsoft's documentation that (using the principals) I could simply use the IsInRole call, but I cannot find any case that doesn't require David to be logged on to the machine or running the application performing the check. I think my limited understanding of the security model also comes into play here.

Could someone please point me in the right direction? What I am looking for is hints on how to solve above (references, tips, snippets) in C#, without depending on David having to run any application.

Let me know if anything can be clarified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a reference to DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Then add a using statement:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

Then  in your main procedure (or somewhere else, where required, call the Procedure IsMember:

```
string userName = "David";
string GroupName = "Team 1";
bool test = IsMember(userName, GroupName);
```

---

```
    public static bool IsMember(string UserName, string GroupName)
    {
        try
        {
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain),
                UserName);

            foreach (Principal result in user.GetAuthorizationGroups())
            {
                if (string.Compare(result.Name, GroupName, true) == 0)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        { 
            throw E; 
        }
    }
```

If David is in Team 1, the procedure will return true, otherwise false.

Comment: Thanks, GetAuthorizationGroups() was the key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344891.aspx) to obtain a `UserPrincipal` object from the directory. This isn't exactly like the other principal objects you may have found, but it does have an [`IsMemberOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337747.aspx) method to allow you to query group membership.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my AD environment

```
var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "GROUPNAME");
var existsInGroup = group.GetMembers(true).Where(p => p.UserPrincipalName == "username@domain").Any();
```

If you don't want to check subgroups, pass `false` to [`GetMembers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339975.aspx).

It doesn't require given user has to be logged on. Hope it helps.